# Separate dated lines into beginning and end of month (LibreOffice)

Tags: sorting, date, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Given a list of items which have a date as one field, how can I separate one set which have a date in the first few days of the month from those which have a date in the last few days?

The items are gas bills, generally one per month, in a bank statement which relate to each of two separate buildings and need to go into two separate accounts.  They were imported from a CSV file.

In practice, the number of lines involved is small, so I've just done it by hand, but the question of how to do it by formula and sort occurred to me, and I neither have nor found an answer.

I hope it is a slightly interesting question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looked for a DayOfTheMonth() function.  Searched for a solution.  Not attempted to write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is simply called `DAY`.  You can find it by clicking on the *Function Wizard* toolbar icon and looking under the *Date&Time* category.

For example, in cell B1 enter a formula like `=DAY(A1)` and fill down.  Then go to *Data -> Sort*.

Comment: Sort of does it.  Then look down the list to where it changes from low number to high number.  

Thanks.  

i may have been looking for too much complication and an IF statement.

Comment: =IF(DAY(A44)<15,"office","home")